# Google is undefined in infobox.js

Tags: google-maps

I have a Google map html page. It works fine in development under localhost but when I try to put in online, I get Google undefined in the infobox.js file, with this line:

this.extend(InfoBubble, google.maps.OverlayView);

I have the api key loaded and it's called before I load the infobox.js file. I added the callback=initialize to see if it would work, but it doesn't work with it or without it. Here is the code for the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Activities</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVVx45quD8ozW5SJZw-Lk_8QvVsXdWi2Y&sensor=false""></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="GoogleMaps/Scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="GoogleMaps/Scripts/infobubble_tabs.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; } 
    .style1
    {
        width: 758px;
    }
    .style2
    {        
        width: 349px;
    }
#side_bar  
{
    height: 550px;
    width: 349px;   
    overflow:scroll;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
        var side_bar_html = "";
        var gmarkers = [];
        var gicons = [];
        var map = null;

        var InfoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            maxWidth: 300
        });


        //defines icon if there is none stated
        gicons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png",
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
        // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
        // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
        // in the top left of the image.
        // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
        // increase in the X direction to the right and in
        // the Y direction down.

        var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png',
        new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
        var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
        // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
        // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final coordinate closes 
        //the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
        var iconShape = {
            coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
            type: 'poly'
        };

        //determines icon based on category
        //if no icon is defined
        function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
            if ((typeof (iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
                iconColor = "red";
            }
            if (!gicons[iconColor]) {
                gicons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconColor,
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
            }
            return gicons[iconColor];
        }

        function category2icon(category) {
            var color = "red";
            switch (category) {
                case "Hike": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/HikingIcon.jpg";
                    break;
                case "KML": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/kml.gif";
                    break;
                case "Camping": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/camping.gif";
                    break;
                case "StatePark": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/statepark.jpg";
                    break;
                case "NationalPark": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/NationalPark_icon.png";
                    break;
                case "PointsofInterest": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/POI.png";
                    break;
                case "CountyPark": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/CountyPark_Icon.png";
                    break;
                case "Biking": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/Bike_icon.jpg";
                    break;
                case "FishWildlifeService": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/FishWildlife_icon.gif";
                    break;
                case "Kayak": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/kayaking.png";
                    break;
                case "Shelter": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/Shelter_Icon.png";
                    break;
                case "Parking": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/Parking_Lot_Icon.png";
                    break;               
                default: color = "red";
                    break;
            }
            return color;
        }

        gicons["Hike"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Hike"));
        gicons["KML"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("KML"));
        gicons["Camping"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Camping"));
        gicons["StatePark"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("StatePark"));
        gicons["NationalPark"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("NationalPark"));
        gicons["PointsofInterest"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("PointsofInterest"));
        gicons["CountyPark"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("CountyPark"));
        gicons["Biking"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Biking"));
        gicons["FishWildlifeService"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("FishWildlifeService"));
        gicons["Kayak"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Kayak"));
        gicons["Shelter"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Shelter"));
        gicons["Parking"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Parking"));

        // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
        function createMarker(latlng, name, url, detail_tab, notes_tab, map_tab, hiking_detail_tab, camping_detail_tab, category, state) {
            var contentString_detail = detail_tab;
            var contentString_notes = notes_tab;
            var contentString_maps = map_tab;
            var contentString_hiking_detail = hiking_detail_tab;
            var contentString_camping_detail = camping_detail_tab;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                icon: gicons[category],
                shadow: iconShadow,
                map: map,
                title: name,
                zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
            });
            // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
            marker.mycategory = category;
            marker.mystate = state;
            marker.myname = name;
            gmarkers.push(marker);

            // to open the info bubbles
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                InfoBubble.open(map, marker);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(4);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(3);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(2);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(1);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(0);
                if (category == "KML") {
                    window.open("" + url);
                }
                if (!category == "KML") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Details', contentString_detail);
                }
                if (!notes_tab == "") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Notes', contentString_notes);
                }
                if (!map_tab == "") {
                    switch (category) {
                        case "Camping": InfoBubble.addTab('Campsite Map', contentString_maps);
                            break;
                        case "Hike": InfoBubble.addTab('Trail Map', contentString_maps);
                            break;
                }
                }
                if (!hiking_detail_tab == "") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Trail Notes', contentString_hiking_detail);
                }
                if (!camping_detail_tab == "") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Campsite Notes', contentString_camping_detail);
                }
            });
        }

        // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
        function show(category) {
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
                    gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            // == check the checkbox ==
            document.getElementById(category + "box").checked = true;
        }

        // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
        function hide(category) {
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
                    gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            // == clear the checkbox ==
            document.getElementById(category + "box").checked = false;
            // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
            InfoBubble.close();
        }

        // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
        function boxclick(box, category) {
            if (box.checked) {
                show(category);
            } else {
                hide(category);
            }
            // == rebuild the side bar
            makeSidebar();
        }

        function myclick(i) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
        }

        // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
        function makeSidebar() {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
                    html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
        }

        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.364032, -77.182159),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            // Closes any open bubbles before opening new one
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {                
                InfoBubble.close();
            });

            //Downloads the data from xml file
            // Reads the data the creates each tab
            downloadUrl("GoogleMaps/categories.xml", function (doc) {
                var xml = xmlParse(doc);
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    // obtain the attribues of each marker
                    var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                    var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                    var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
                    var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
                    var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("zip");
                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                    var notes = markers[i].getAttribute("notes");
                    var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
                    var hike_distance = markers[i].getAttribute("hike_distance");
                    var hike_trail_skill_level = markers[i].getAttribute("hike_trail_skill_level");
                    var hike_points_of_interest = markers[i].getAttribute("hike_points_of_interest");
                    var Camping_Amenities = markers[i].getAttribute("Camping_Amenities");
                    var Camping_Best_Sites = markers[i].getAttribute("Camping_Best_Sites");
                    var Camping_Notes = markers[i].getAttribute("Camping_Notes");
                    var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
                    var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
                    //Creates data for Detail Tab
                    var detail_tab = "";
                    detail_tab += "<b>" + name + "<\/b><p>";
                    detail_tab += address + "</br>";
                    detail_tab += city + ", " + state + " " + zip + "</br>";
                    detail_tab += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>' + "</br>";
                    //Creates data for Notes Tab
                    var notes_tab = notes;
                    //Creates data for Maps Tab
                    var map_tab = "";
                    if (image) {
                        map_tab += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + image + '">' + image + '</a>' + "</br>";
                    }
                    //Creates data for Hiking Detail Tab                    
                    var hiking_detail_tab = "";
                    if (hike_distance) {
                        hiking_detail_tab += "<b>Trail Distance: </b>" + hike_distance + " miles</br>";
                        hiking_detail_tab += "<b>Trail Skill Level: </b>" + hike_trail_skill_level + "</br>";
                        hiking_detail_tab += "<b>Points of Interest: </b>" + hike_points_of_interest + "</br>";
                    }
                    //Creates data for Camping Detail Tab                    
                    var camping_detail_tab = "";
                    if (Camping_Notes) {
                        camping_detail_tab += "<b>Amenities: </b>" + Camping_Amenities + "</br>";
                        camping_detail_tab += "<b>Best Sites: </b>" + Camping_Best_Sites + "</br>";
                        camping_detail_tab += "<b>Notes: </b>" + Camping_Notes + "</br>";
                    }
                   // var kml_tab = "";
                   // if (category=="KML) {
                    // create the marker
                    var marker = createMarker(point, name, url, detail_tab, notes_tab, map_tab, hiking_detail_tab, camping_detail_tab, category);
                }

                // == show or hide the categories initially ==
                show("Hike");
                show("KML");
                hide("Camping");
                hide("StatePark");
                hide("NationalPark");
                hide("PointsofInterest");
                hide("CountyPark");
                hide("Biking");
                hide("FishWildlifeService");
                hide("Kayak");
                hide("Shelter");
                hide("Parking");
                // == create the initial sidebar ==
                makeSidebar();
            });
        }


    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 
    <table border="1" >
      <tr>
        <td class="style1">
           <div id="map" style="width:978px; height: 596px"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;" 
              class="style2">
              <h4>To view a topo map, click map in the top left corner and select terrain from drop down menu</h4> 
           <div id="side_bar"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="#">
      Hiking: <input type="checkbox" id="Hikebox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Hike')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Full Trail Map: <input type="checkbox" id="KMLbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'KML')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Trail Shelters: <input type="checkbox" id="Shelterbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Shelter')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Trail Parking: <input type="checkbox" id="Parkingbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Parking')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Camping: <input type="checkbox" id="Campingbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Camping')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Biking: <input type="checkbox" id="Bikingbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Biking')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Kayaking: <input type="checkbox" id="Kayakbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Kayak')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <br />
      State Parks: <input type="checkbox" id="StateParkbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'StatePark')" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      National Parks: <input type="checkbox" id="NationalParkbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'NationalPark')" />&nbsp;&nbsp;   
      County Park: <input type="checkbox" id="CountyParkbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'CountyPark')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <br />
      Points of Interest: <input type="checkbox" id="PointsofInterestbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'PointsofInterest')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;  
      Fish and Wildlife Service: <input type="checkbox" id="FishWildlifeServicebox" onclick="boxclick(this,'FishWildlifeService')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;      
      <br />
    </form>  




    <noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
      However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
      To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
      try again.
    </noscript>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with InfoBox [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_customMarkersA.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `callback`-parameter. When you use the callback-parameter the asynchronous version of the maps-API will be loaded.

You can't use the asynchronous version of the API here because infobox.js only works when the maps-API has already been loaded(what may happen with the asynchronous version, but must not).
In this special case the API never will be loaded, because the body-element is still unknown (but it must be available, because the script tries to inject  another script-element into the body).

When you say that it also doesn't work without the callback-parameter there must be another issue that will not be exposed by the code, please post more code or a demo/link.

Comment: I posted the entire html file. I didn't have enough room to do the infobubble code but its the public domain code, search infobubble_Tabs.js for the code, I made no changes to it. Could it be the API key? Does the key need to be linked to a URL address somehow?

Comment: post a link to that page

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js?r=49

Comment: I mean your page, where you got the problem.

Comment: The only thing that's wrong there is the infobox.js , line 37 actually is  `this.extend(InfoBubble, http://www.google.maps.OverlayView); ` ,  but it has to be `this.extend(InfoBubble, google.maps.OverlayView); `

Comment: That is the line that says Google is undefined. I changed it to see if it would help and didn't change it back. I can't find anything wrong with it either but only the map comes up with no bookmarks. On the IIS server, when you try to load it locally, you get the Google is undefined on that line. I don't know what to do at this point. It works great on my desktop but doesn't work on the server.

Comment: The bookmarks don't work because of the failed loading of categories.xml . The xml-file is served with content-type `text/html` , but the browser only accepts a content-type `application/xml` for this file. Setup the server to serve xml-files with the correct content-type.